# Express route params get error with firefox and mobile browser

Tags: express, firefox, aws-lambda, httprequest, backend

I’ve been having this strange error with my express backend, where I get an error from Firefox and mobile browsers when accessing the params included in my path. When I send the request from Chrome, it works fine. Although I know how to get around it, I’m really curious as to what’s not actually working.

For example, I have been having a ton of trouble with this path:

```javascript
router.route('/:id/:restaurantId/addRequest').post((req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;

    const newRequest = new Request({ name });

    Organization.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(org => {
            const i = org.restaurants.findIndex(rest => rest._id == req.params.restaurantId);

            if (org.restaurants[i].requests.findIndex(req => req.name == name) === -1) {

            org.restaurants[i].requests.push(newRequest);

            org.save()
                .then(() => res.json('Request Added.'))
                .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
            } else {
                res.json('Request Already Exists');
            }

        })
});
```

But when I tried modifying the path so that I just send the params I need in the request JSON object I send, it works fine.

```javascript
router.route('/addRequest').post((req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;

    const newRequest = new Request({ name });

    Organization.findById(req.body.orgID)
        .then(org => {
            const i = org.restaurants.findIndex(rest => rest._id == req.body.restID);

            if (org.restaurants[i].requests.findIndex(req => req.name == name) === -1) {

            org.restaurants[i].requests.push(newRequest);

            org.save()
                .then(() => res.json('Request Added.'))
                .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
            } else {
                res.json('Request Already Exists');
            }

        })
});
```

It’s possible that this isn’t actually the underlying issue, but, based on everything I’ve tested, a route only breaks when I have some sort of route params. If anyone could give me some clarity that’d be awesome.

Here are all the routes within the file I'm having trouble with:

```js
router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
    Organization.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(Organizations => res.json(Organizations))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    const id = req.body.id;
    const name = req.body.name;
    const restaurants = [];

    const newOrganization = new Organization({ name, restaurants });
    newOrganization._id = id;

    newOrganization.save()
        .then(() => res.json('Organization added!'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));


});

router.route('/:id/addRestaurant').post((req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const requests = [];
    const tables = [];

    const newRestaurant = new Restaurant({ name, requests, tables });

    Organization.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(org => {
            org.restaurants.push(newRestaurant);

            org.save()
                .then(() => res.json('Restaurant Added.'))
                .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
        })
});

router.route('/:id/:restaurantId/addTable').post((req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const code = req.body.code;

    const newTable = new Table({ name, code });

    Organization.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(org => {
            const i = org.restaurants.findIndex(rest => rest._id == req.params.restaurantId);
            org.restaurants[i].tables.push(newTable);

            org.save()
                .then(() => res.json('Table Added.'))
                .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
        })
});

router.route('/:id/:restaurantId/addRequest').post((req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;

    const newRequest = new Request({ name });

    Organization.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(org => {
            const i = org.restaurants.findIndex(rest => rest._id == req.params.restaurantId);

            if (org.restaurants[i].requests.findIndex(req => req.name == name) === -1) {

            org.restaurants[i].requests.push(newRequest);

            org.save()
                .then(() => res.json('Request Added.'))
                .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
            } else {
                res.json('Request Already Exists');
            }

        })
});

router.route('/:id/:restaurantId/getTables').get((req, res) => {
    Organization.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(org => {
            const i = org.restaurants.findIndex(rest => rest._id == req.params.restaurantId);
            res.json(org.restaurants[i].tables);
        })
})

router.route('/:id/:restaurantId/getRequests').get((req, res) => {
    Organization.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(org => {
            const i = org.restaurants.findIndex(rest => rest._id == req.params.restaurantId);
            res.json(org.restaurants[i].requests);
        })
})

router.route('/:id/:restaurantId/deleteTable').post((req, res) => {
    Organization.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(org => {
            const i = org.restaurants.findIndex(rest => rest._id == req.params.restaurantId);
            org.restaurants[i].tables = org.restaurants[i].tables.filter(table => table.code !== req.body.code)

            org.save()
                .then(() => res.json('Table Deleted.'))
                .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
})

router.route('/:id/:restaurantId/deleteRequest').post((req, res) => {
    Organization.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(org => {
            console.log(req.body.id);
            const i = org.restaurants.findIndex(rest => rest._id == req.params.restaurantId);
            org.restaurants[i].requests = org.restaurants[i].requests.filter(request => request._id != req.body.id)

            org.save()
                .then(() => res.json('Request Deleted.'))
                .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
})

router.route('/:id/:restaurantId/updateCode').post((req, res) => {
    Organization.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(org => {
            const i = org.restaurants.findIndex(rest => rest._id == req.params.restaurantId);
            org.restaurants[i].tables.forEach(table => {
                if (req.body.oldCode === table.code)
                    table.code = req.body.newCode;
            });

            org.save()
                .then(() => res.json('Code Updated.'))
                .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
})
```

Comment: can you add all router to the question. I want to see the order of the routes

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi Just added them